# Таблица с помощью jQuery ui

Tags: html, jquery-ui

Как подключить грид таблицу с jquery ui,или такого нет?(тогда остается плагин gridTable) Хотелось бы пользоваться с грид-виджетом(чтоб оформить таблицу) если есть конечно в комплекте  стандартного jquery ui. Но в демке только календарь, кнопки, диалог, прогресбар, и т. д .Не нашел там грида.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может быть, [SocialCalc](http://plugindetector.com/socialcalc) вам поможет? Еще варианты есть на [plugindetecror.com](http://plugindetector.com/category/tables)

Comment: Спасибо.Но это слишком громоздкий, выбрал
tablesorter.